# How to disable autofill on ember form field

Tags: javascript, ember.js

I have a form for updating the details of `alumni` in ember using RESTful api. Is it possible to prevent the form from auto filling the data I previously entered in the form corresponding to another record in the model?

I have these codes in my update route directory(I am using pod-structure):

**controller.js**

```
# app/alumnis/update/controller.js
import Controller from '@ember/controller';
import { get, set } from '@ember/object';

export default Controller.extend({
  firstName: null,

  actions: {
    updateAlumni(value) {
      let firstName = get(this, 'firstName');
      if(firstName) {
        firstName = firstName.charAt(0).toUpperCase() + firstName.slice(1).toLowerCase();
        this.get('store').findRecord('alumni', value).then(function(alumni) {
          alumni.set('firstName', firstName);
          alumni.save();
        });
      }
      this.transitionToRoute('alumnis.show', value)
    },
  },
});
```

**route.js**

```
# app/alumnis/update/route.js
import Route from '@ember/routing/route';
import { set } from '@ember/object';

export default Route.extend({
  model(params) {
    return this.store.findRecord('alumni', params.id);
  },

  setupController(controller, model) {
    set(controller, 'alumni', model);
  }
});
```

**template.hbs**

```
# app/alumnis/update/template.hbs
<form class="alumniForm" {{action "updateAlumni" on="submit"}}>
  <div class="form-group">
    <h3>First Name : {{input name="firstName" type="text" value=firstName placeholder=alumni.firstName autocomplete="off"}}</h3>
  </div>
  <button class="btn btn-primary" {{action "updateAlumni" alumni.id}}>Submit</button>
</form>
```

**router.js**

```
# app/router.js
import EmberRouter from '@ember/routing/router';
import config from './config/environment';

const Router = EmberRouter.extend({
  location: config.locationType,
  rootURL: config.rootURL
});

Router.map(function() {
  this.route('alumnis', function() {
    this.route('show', {path: '/:id'});
    this.route('add', {path: '/add'});
    this.route('update', {path: '/:id/update'});
  });
});

export default Router;
```

On the first rendering of `update` route after every reloading, no form fields are filled automatically. But, once we enter data to the `firstName` input field, it is rendered to form field in `update` page of any other record in the model `alumni`.

Comment: what have you tried? this is typically a browser feature or browser extension feature, and it's up to the browser to decide whether or not to respect `autocomplete="off"` on the form / inputs.

https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/Security/Securing_your_site/Turning_off_form_autocompletion

Comment: @NullVoxPopuli , I have tried turning `autocomplete="off"` and access the `route` in incognito mode, but the field are rendered even before clicking the input box in the form

Comment: the fields will always be rendered? I'm confused now

Comment: The field is rendered to previously entered value in the `update` route of any record in the model `alumni`. Placeholder value is the actual value from the record but the field is autofilled to data given as input when this route is previously visited.

Comment: if you try a totally different browser does it still autofill?

Comment: I'm just wondering if this is an app logic issue or browser autofill/autocomplete

Comment: I tried it using both chrome and safari. Now, I am able to achieve it. And thank you for the comments

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I was able to resolve the issue by changing the below codes:

**controller.js**

```
# app/alumnis/update/controller.js
import Controller from '@ember/controller';
import { get, set } from '@ember/object';

export default Controller.extend({
  firstName: null,

  actions: {
    updateAlumni(value) {
      let alumni = get(this, 'alumni');
      let changedAttrs = alumni.changedAttributes();
      if(changedAttrs.firstName) {
        let firstName = alumni.firstName.toLowerCase().capitalize();
        alumni.set('firstName', firstName);
        alumni.save()
      }
      this.transitionToRoute('alumnis.show', value)
    },
  },
});
```

**template.hbs**

```
# app/alumnis/update/template.hbs
<form class="alumniForm" autocomplete="off" {{action "updateAlumni" on="submit"}}>
  <div class="form-group">
    <h3>First Name : {{input name="firstName" type="text" value=alumni.firstName}}</h3>
  </div>
  <button class="btn btn-primary" {{action "updateAlumni" alumni.id}}>Submit</button>
</form>
```

No change in `app/alumnis/update/route.js`

Answer (score 3):

Properties that are set in a controller in ember will remain set when you re-navigate to the page.
The logic you've shown, leads me to believe you don't even need the controller.  You are modifying a model property, saving it and transitioning.
You were doing a round-about way of updating the record, The alumni record was your model, yet you were trying to re-fetch it from the store.

**route.js**

```
# app/alumnis/update/route.js
import Route from '@ember/routing/route';
import { set,get } from '@ember/object';

export default Route.extend({
  model(params) {
    return this.store.findRecord('alumni', params.id);
  },

  updateAlumni() {
      let changedAttrs = get(this, 'model').changedAttributes();
      if (changedAttrs.firstName) {
        let firstName = get(this, 'model.firstName').toLowerCase().capitalize();
        set('model.firstName', firstName);
      }
      get(this,'model').save()
      this.transitionToRoute('alumnis.show', get(this,'model'))
    }
});
```

**template.hbs**

```
# app/alumnis/update/template.hbs
<form class="alumniForm" {{action "updateAlumni" on="submit"}}>
  <div class="form-group">
    <h3>First Name : {{input name="firstName" type="text" value=model.firstName placeholder=alumni.firstName autocomplete="off"}}</h3>
  </div>
  <button class="btn btn-primary" {{action "updateAlumni"}}>Submit</button>
</form>
```

Comment: I am getting an error: Assertion Failed: You attempted to define a `{{link-to "alumnis.update"}}` but did not pass the parameters required for generating its dynamic segments.  Expected to find: `controller:alumnis/update` within `amp/alumnis/update/controller` but got `undefined`. Did you forget to 'export default' within `amp/alumnis/update/controller`?"

Comment: After changing the `updateAlumni()` function in the `controller.js` file and using `value=alumni.firstName` in `template.hbs` I was able to avoid the issue.

Comment: Do you still have the controller file sitting around? Are you passing an id or model as the second parameter for link-to?

Comment: I am passing the `alumni.id` as second argument for link-to.